# how to Enable/Disable asp panel and children using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I created this jQuery to Enable/Disable child Form Elements inside the asp.net panel this script will enable edit form but it will not Disable it after i click for second time can someone help me ?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            //creating toggle
            $("#check").button();

            $("[id$='check']").data('isenabled', true); //enabled assumption
            //disabled all input form 
            $("[id$=p_taskInfo]").children().prop("disabled", "disabled");
            $("input[name='check']").click(function () {
                var currentState = $(this).data('isenabled');
                if (currentState) {
                    $("[id$=p_taskInfo]").children().removeProp("disabled");
                }
                else {
                    $("[id$=p_taskInfo]").children().prop("disabled", "disabled");
                }
                $(this).data('isenabled', !currentState);
            }); //EOF click function 
        });//EOF function 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*currentState* was spelled wrong and you need to swop the two statements in the if...else blocks around, like this:

```
 <asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("[id$=p_taskInfo]").children().prop("disabled", "disabled");
            $("input[name='check']").click(function () {
                var currentState = $(this).data('isenabled');
                if (currentState) {
                    $("[id$=p_taskInfo]").children().prop("disabled", "disabled");
                }
                else {
                    $("[id$=p_taskInfo]").children().removeProp("disabled");
                }
                $(this).data('isenabled', !currentState);
            });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <input id="check" name="check" type="button" value="Enable\Disable" />
    <asp:Panel ID="p_taskInfo" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: the code Enable the panel but if I  click to  disable it want work

Comment: In your question you state that you want the same button to enable\disable the panel. The code above solves just that solution.You have not posted any .ASPX markup so I've just created some dummy data on my side

Comment: And what's the reason for unmarking as unswered?I showed you exactly where you were going wrong?This is very dishonest and I don't appreciate it